How to use google map tiles with MapKit?
I need to attach google map tiles as MKTileOverlay to MapKit.
Google documentation tells me to use url template like "https://tile.googleapis.com/tile/v1/viewport?session=YOUR_SESSION_TOKEN&key=YOUR_API_KEY&zoom=ZOOM&north=NORTH&south=SOUTH&east=EAST&west=WEST".
But MKTileOverlay expects url in other format, like this "https://tiles.x-gpsmail.com/iry8ordl8v/styles/squaregps-basic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
I assume, i need to override MKTileOverlay func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL, but i have no idea how to construct it according to google template
Or maybe some other way to use google tiles with MapKit?
(i can't use google maps sdk due to big number of custom logic already running over MapKit sdk)

Please carefully read google's terms and conditions. Some results may only be used in Googles maps. Not sure if this also holds for tiles.

i have figured out. here is suitable url format for MapKit
curl "https://tile.googleapis.com/v1/2dtiles/z/x/y?session=YOUR_SESSION_TOKEN&key=YOUR_API_KEY&orientation=0_or_90_or_180_or_270"
